# Symbolic link not allowed apache 2.4 chiliproject

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, chiliproject

Few hours ago I upgraded ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 LTS. I have 1 problem with chiliproject application wich running on Rails.

I got error 403 when I'm trying to access my chiliproject application. In apache2 error log i got:

```
Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accesibble /var/www/chili
```

In my apache2 conf i got:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options  FollowSymLinks MultiViews SymLinksIfOwnerMatch  
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
#       Order allow,deny
#       allow from all
    </Directory>    


    RailsBaseURI /chili

    <Directory /var/www/chili>
            AllowOverride all
            Options -MultiViews
        Require all granted
#           Order deny,allow
#           Allow from all
     </Directory>
```

I don't know why it's not running. Passenger is running and I'm stuck. Can somebody please help me ?

I tried to check users ownership in catalogs:

```
 ls -ld /var/www/chili 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 41 gru 31 2013 /var/www/chili -> /var/www/chiliproject/chiliproject/public
```

And Target

```
 drwxrwxrwx 4 chiliproject root 4096 gru 31 2013 chiliproject/
```

Answer (score 0):

change the ownership of /var/www/chili using

`sudo chown -R www-data: /var/www/chili`

and preferably the ownership of parent dir /var/www as well.

Restart apache2

Apache will be able to read if the owner is www-data.